# Python is going out of range on the ')' character

Tags: python

So I am supposed to be solving an algorithm question where if you have "{}" or "()" or "[]" the string is valid - if a related brace is opened and closed next to each other, they are valid and you can continue to parse the string.

Here is my code:

```
def isValid(self, s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return False
    compare = ""
    for i, element in enumerate(s):
        compare = ""
        compare += (element)
        if compare == "(":
            if s[i + 1] == ")":
                continue
            else:
                return False
        if compare == '{':
            if s[i + 1] == '}':
                continue
            else:
                return False
        if compare == '[':
            if s[i + 1] == ']':
                continue
            else:
                return False
    return True
```

Somewhere around the calculation for ")" aka the first if statement, it is going out of range.

Error thrown: Runtime Error Message:

```
Line 14: IndexError: string index out of range
Last executed input:
"){"
```

I've tested this with a string such as "){{])" and it returns false correctly. However, it will error on "){"

Why is this?

Update: Forget the index. I just couldn't understand why. The index value should be i when we check, which is still index 0...I'm just not getting it. So I rewrote the code and used a stack:

```
def isValid(self, s):
    stack = []
    dict = {"]":"[", "}":"{", ")":"("}
    for char in s:
        if char in dict.values():
            stack.append(char)
        elif char in dict.keys():
            if stack == [] or dict[char] != stack.pop():
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return stack == []
```

Comment: If the `(` is the last character of the string, `s[i+1]` is out of range.

Comment: I suspect that `i == len(s)-1` when this fails.

Comment: `s[i + 1]` in a `for i, x in enumerate(s)` or `for i in range(len(s))` will always get you out of range.  You're literally asking for one more candy when you took the last piece from the candy jar.

Comment: @Barmar Why is that? Is this some syntactical error? Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: You're trying to test the next character. If the current character is the last character, there is no next character, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @travis your loop is defined to run until `s` is the index of the last element in the list. Then you attempt to access index `s+1`. Since `s` is already the last index, `s+1` is guaranteed to be out of range.

Comment: @zinki I thought I was providing the first element to “compare” then comparing it right away with the next element. The snippet where I am setting compare += element, I thought was going to be ‘)’, then automatically compare it to s[I + 1]. That’s what I wanted to do, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tested this with a string such as "){{])" and it returns false
>   correctly. However, it will error on "){"
>
> Why is this?

Let's break down your code:

1.) `s = "){"`, `s` has 2 elements, namely:

```
element: ) {
index:   0 1
```

2.) When you `enumerate(s)`, the iteration runs twice:

3.) The first iteration, `i == 0`, you're testing against `s[0] == ")"`.
4.) Your code have no condition to check for `s[0] == ")"` directly under the iteration, so nothing happens.

5.) The second iteration, `i == 1`, you're testing against `s[1] == "{"`.
6.) Your code have a condition (`if compare == '{':`) to check for `s[1] == "{"`.  The `if` condition is now active.  Now your code tries to execute the following:

```
 if s[i + 1] == '}':
```

7.) You're at the second (and last) iteration.  The `if` statement tries to get `s[i + 1]` to test the condition.  However `s[1 + 1]` which is `s[2]`.
8.) Recall the elements and index in your 's':

```
element: ) { 
index:   0 1 
             ^ 
             doesn't exist
```

9.) `s[2]` doesn't exist.  Python flips out and yells at you for requesting an index out of range.

> Forget the index. I just couldn't understand why.

**Don't.**  You'll forever make the same mistake.

Learn, understand, and overcome it.  It's the only way to improve.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I was so burnt out from coding yesterday that I didn't realize I wasn't checking for if I ever gave the value ")"!!! I was only checking against one value char, therefore of COURSE it would iterate a second time without me knowing! My gosh thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here `i` is the index of `s`:

```
for i, element in enumerate(s):
```

but later you try to index at `i+1`:

```
        if s[i + 1]
```

This will fail if `i` is the last index of `s` and you index out side of `s`.